# SharePoint 2010 Patch update

Tags: sharepoint-server, cumulative-update, patching

I am working on assignment to update SharePoint 2010 Farm Servers ( app and WFE servers) Patch update from SP1 to latest one, which we have right now, can someone guide what should be the steps.

Please correct me if I am wrong; that CU will include all the old patches update including SP2 ?

Do I need to install Dec 2019 Updates ( is it the last and latest CU update available) or I have to install all the updates, as mentioned on this link for 2010 https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/officeupdates/sharepoint-updates

Somewhere I find below steps for installing patch updates on SharePoint Servers, please correct me if I am wrong:

1. Download the CU and document the issues it is purported to resolve
2. Install the CU on a non-production environment FIRST and TEST IT!!
3. Prepare the production SharePoint environment
4. Document the production environment BEFORE patching
5. Dismount ALL SharePoint content databases
6. Install the CU on each farm server
7. Run PSConfig on all servers
8. Re-mount all content databases
9. Ensure ALL content databases have been re-mounted successfully
10. Run content database upgrade script(s)
11. Document the production SharePoint environment AFTER patching
12. Verify production farm functionality

Comment: That looks correct to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, December 2019 (KB4484195) is the latest update for SharePoint server 2010. You don't need to install all the updates.

To apply [December 10, 2019, cumulative update for SharePoint Server 2010 (KB4484195)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4484195/december-10-2019-cumulative-update-for-sharepoint-server-2010-kb448419), you must have [Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010 Service Pack 2 (SP2)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2687453/description-of-sharepoint-server-2010-sp2) installed.

Installing SharePoint 2010 Cumulative Updates for your reference:

https://richardstk.com/2011/08/09/installing-sharepoint-2010-cumulative-updates/